# How to discover mistakes in faith?

Tags: faith

There are many possibilities how to twist the faith.

For example: assumptions, prejudices, misinterpretation, unintentional deception, projecting wishes... These things can twist the spiritual way,

How do I find out if someone's faith was twisted?

Comment: Could you clarify this? It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Tentative interpretation: "There are many ways one can damage one's faith like making assumptions, various prejudices, misinterpreting parts of the Bible, unintentional self-deception, projecting wishes into what one reads, etc. How can I discover and correct these things?"

Comment: @wax eagle: I don't know how. Can you specify what is unclear?

Comment: @Jan the grammar doesn't actually make sense, but thats not really the issue. Its really more that I'm not sure what your goal is with this question. Could you expand it a bit?

Comment: @wax eagle: I was doing my best. How about this?

Comment: @Jan - I tried to clarify it a bit. I think its better. I'm not convinced its answerable, but its better.

Comment: @wax eagle: I got the point - to separate the question from other text and to point out just one thing in one paragraph. That is also useful, yet unexpected answer, so thank you, too :-)

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of 1 sentence per paragraph, but sometimes its necessary for clarification, as in this instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very valid concern. Here are some suggestions that come to mind.

- Study the word regularly. Pray that God would teach it to you and approach it as something that will shape you, not something you need to find support for your cause in. Systematic reading really aides this rather than following along with whatever verses somebody else quotes for whatever cause.
- Keep your eye on other traditions. This doesn't mean church hop and float between belief systems, but it does mean keeping up on some reading, listening to some preachers you don't agree with just to make sure the ones you do are really saying something, studying different bible translations to help you get a full grasp of the word.
- Stay in fellowship with other believers. Find a community that is both well grounded and diverse. The discussions, interactions and iron sharpening iron is what will keep you on the right track. A community where questioning something and examining the basis for things is not welcomed is not a safe place to be. Likewise a community that does not value truth or place any guards on itself at all is also a dangerous place to be. Use lots of discretion.
- Don't be stubborn willed when you learn you're wrong about some little thing. Keep an attitude of humility and and pray regularly about what areas you need to learn and grow in. If God is trying to show you something through any of the things you need to be ready to hear it. Don't be blown around by every wave of teaching that comes along but do keep.

Lastly and most importantly, don't stop [looking to Jesus, the founder and perfecter of our faith](http://www.esvbible.org/search/Hebrews%2012:2).

Comment: Great answer. It seems to solve even more, especially the fourth one. Thank you.